# EF Core Parent Child Relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class `Product` which may have Addons and also be an Addon of Parent Products.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Parents { get; set; }
    public List<ProductAddon> ParentProducts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Addons { get; set; }
    public List<ProductAddon> AddonProducts { get; set; }
}
```

The class that represents the join table.

```
public class ProductAddon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Product { get; set; }
    public Addon { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

How do I setup this in OnModelCreating to be working?

Answer (score 0):

```
 entity.HasOne(d => d.ProductAddon)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Product)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("ConstaintNameFromSQL");
```

EDIT:
For a many to many relationship, you have to create a pivot table->
A table that has a FK to both tables you have a many to many in, and I would recommend a PK, for each line as well, as you never know if you might want it to become an aggregate table.

Model pseudo below:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductProductAddonPivot>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.ToTable("ProductProductAddonPivot", "YourDbSchemaNameHere");//

// other possible properties
entity.Property(e => e.ProductId).HasColumnName("ProductId");
entity.Property(e => e.ProductAddonId).HasColumnName("ProductAddonId");

// other possible constraints

         entity.HasOne(d => d.Product)
                            .WithMany(p => p.ProductProductAddOnPivot)
                            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductId)
                            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                            .HasConstraintName("ConstaintNameFromSQL");
    
     entity.HasOne(d => d.ProductAddon)
                        .WithMany(p => p.ProductProductAddOnPivot)
                        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductAddonId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                        .HasConstraintName("ConstaintNameFromSQL2");
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately its not that easy. a product can have all other products as addon and/or as parents.

Comment: updated by answer to the many to many pivot table solution

Comment: Or did I misunderstand you, and you mean that you need a reference to "product to product"